# What would be a good alternative to using lookbehind with unknown number of characters (not bounded maximum length)?

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector of values of the following format:

```
c("T12_50;Y13_50;Y3_33", "Y15_100")
```

I need to extract the values after the following three elements

- Y
- a number with unknown number of digits
- an underscore

In this case the first element ("T12_50;Y13_50;Y3_33") should yeild c(50, 33) and the second element ("Y15_100") should yield c(100).

```
str_extract_all ("T12_50;Y13_50;Y3_33", "(?<=Y\\d+_)\\d+")
```

but it produces an error

> Look-Behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length.

after playing around I understood that the issue is I cannot have "d+" in the lookbehind portion of regex. What would be the alternative here?

Comment: Can't you use groups instead of a look-behind? Something like `Y\d+_(\d+)` and catch group 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend **[`stringr::str_match_all`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/0.6.2/topics/str_match_all) with a regex modification**, where the positive lookbehind is turned into a consuming pattern and the part you need to return is wrapped in capturing parentheses (i.e. *`(?<=Y\d+_)\d+`* -> *`Y\d+_(\d+)`*):

```r
x <- c("T12_50;Y13_50;Y3_33", "Y15_100")
library(stringr)
res <- lapply(str_match_all(x, "Y\\d+_(\\d+)"), function(m) m[,-1])
```

Or a **base R solution**, where a PCRE regex is used, in which the part you do not need can be "truncated" with the help of the `\K` operator (i.e. *`(?<=Y\d+_)\d+`* -> *`Y\d+_\K\d+`*):

```r
res <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("Y\\d+_\\K\\d+", x, perl=TRUE))
```

`res` then will hold

```
[[1]]
[1] "50" "33"

[[2]]
[1] "100"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/2dCYa7).

Yes, thanks to the fact that `stringr` package uses [ICU regex library](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html#regular-expression-operators) that supports constrained-width lookbehinds, you can really use `stringr::str_extract_all(x, "(?<=Y\\d{1,100}_)\\d+")` if you are sure there can be no more than 100 and no less than 1 digit between `Y` and `_`. You just can't use `*` and `+` inside ICU regex lookbehinds:

> The length of possible strings matched by the look-behind pattern must not be unbounded (no `*` or `+` operators.)

Comment: could you please explain what a "consuming pattern" is?

Comment: @PavelShliaha Lookarounds, anchors, word boundaries are non-consuming - they do not advance the regex index. All the rest that match text, put it into the match memory buffer and advance regex index are consuming.

Answer (score 1):

If you knew there was some reasonably finite number of digits that exists between the "Y" and underscore ("_"), you can specify this in your existing regex.

Below I have tweaked your existing code and assumed that there are between 0 and 100 digits in the "Yxxx_" portion (using `\\d{0,100}` instead of `\\d+`):

```
x <- c("T12_50;Y13_50;Y3_33", "Y15_100")

stringr::str_extract_all(x, "(?<=Y\\d{0,100}_)\\d+") 
[[1]]
[1] "50" "33"

[[2]]
[1] "100"
```

Or based on @LMC's excellent comment, you can find the max number and `paste0` it into the regex:

```
x <- c("T12_50;Y13_50;Y3_33", "Y15_100")

# thanks @LMc
maxn <- max(nchar(unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(x, "(?<=Y)\\d+(?=_)"))), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 2

stringr::str_extract_all(x, paste0("(?<=Y\\d{0,", maxn, "}_)\\d+")) 

[[1]]
[1] "50" "33"

[[2]]
[1] "100"
```

If there is not a reasonable maximum number, a base R alternative is to use `strsplit` to split on the semicolon then `gsub` after indexing on if it contains a "Y". This will provide identical results:

```
lapply(strsplit(x, ";"), \(y) 
       gsub("Y\\d+_","", y[grep("Y\\d+_", y)]))

[[1]]
[1] "50" "33"

[[2]]
[1] "100"
```

Comment: @LMc great point! I edited this in as well as how to paste it into the regex. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This produces a useful result.

```
sapply( x, function(z) {z<- scan(text=z, what="",sep=";") 
         as.numeric(sub("(Y[[:digit:]]+_)([[:digit:]]+)", "\\2", z ))} )
#---------------------
Read 3 items
Read 1 item
$`T12_50;Y13_50;Y3_33`
[1] NA 50 33

$Y15_100
[1] 100
```

You might want to `unname` and `na.omit` the result:

```
 unname( sapply( x, function(z) {z<- scan(text=z, what="",sep=";") 
          na.omit(as.numeric(sub("(Y[[:digit:]]+_)([[:digit:]]+)", "\\2", z )))} ))
#-------------
Read 3 items
Read 1 item
[[1]]
[1] 50 33
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 1
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"

[[2]]
[1] 100

Warning message:
In na.omit(as.numeric(sub("(Y[[:digit:]]+_)([[:digit:]]+)", "\\2",  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, use `regmatches`: Note that we use `\K` which resets the starting position.

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("Y\\d+_\\K\\d+", x, perl = TRUE))

[[1]]
[1] "50" "33"

[[2]]
[1] "100"
```

---

```
strsplit(trimws(gsub("Y\\d+_(\\d+)|.", "\\1 ", x)), " +")
[[1]]
[1] "50" "33"

[[2]]
[1] "100"
```

Comment: Note: your first answer involving `\K` is a duplicate answer.